# Purescript treats class as circular type synonym

Tags: purescript

I'm trying to define instances that only work on type level natural numbers. When I compile this file:

```
module Main where

data NatZero
data NatSucc n

class NatClass n where
   switch :: f NatZero -> (forall m. NatClass m => f (NatSucc m)) -> f n
```

it tells me:

```
Error found:
at src/Main.purs:6:1 - 7:73 (line 6, column 1 - line 7, column 73)

  A cycle appears in the definition of type synonym NatClass
  Cycles are disallowed because they can lead to loops in the type checker.
  Consider using a 'newtype' instead.
```

Why did NatClass become a type synonym? I thought it was a type class. And where is there a loop? What should I change to make this work like in Haskell? It's telling me to newtype, what do I newtype?

Comment: (This code was taken from https://wiki.haskell.org/Closed_world_instances)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is misleading and unfortunate - it's not anything you're doing wrong with the code here, it's happening due to how the compiler desugars type classes.

Currently a dictionary is represented as a record, so the synonym mentioned in the error here is because the compiler creates something like this for the class:

```
type NatClass n = 
  { switch :: forall f. f NatZero -> (forall m. NatClass m => f (NatSucc m)) -> f n }
```

So that it can do a fairly direct replacement of constraints with dictionary arguments.

I think right now this class (or any that uses itself as a constraint in a member) will have the same problem.

I've been wanting to change the representation for type classes for a while, and have a [WIP PR](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/pull/3567) for it, I think after that this kind of thing will be allowed. After this classes will be desugared into a `data` type rather than a synonym, so the reference should be allowed.

Comment: Hmm... how does the compiler currently desugar type classes?

Comment: I've edited the answer to elaborate - short version: they're records.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the Purescript limitation pretty easily by reifying the dictionary yourself. Something like -

```hs
data NatZero
data NatSucc n

newtype NatClassDict n = NatClassDict (forall f. f NatZero -> (forall m. NatClass m => f (NatSucc m)) -> f n)

getSwitch :: NatClassDict n -> (forall f. f NatZero -> (forall m. NatClass m => f (NatSucc m)) -> f n)
getSwitch (NatClassDict f) = f

class NatClass n where
  natClassDict :: NatClassDict n

switch :: NatClass n => forall f. f NatZero -> (forall m. NatClass m => f (NatSucc m)) -> f n
switch = getSwitch natClassDict
```